# Error Encountered Running 'https://github.com/pranz24/pytorch-soft-actor-critic' : Mujoco Compilation Failure with Missing 'mjui.h' File

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

When I tried to run the `main.py` file from the link https://github.com/pranz24/pytorch-soft-actor-critic, I encountered the following error (the error message is placed at the bottom).

Environment:

- Python 3.8
- Windows 11.

I'm not sure if this is related to my not downloading the complete Mujoco. I followed the tutorial at https://blog.csdn.net/fangchenglia/article/details/124286509 (a Chinese website) for the operation. Specifically, I downloaded `mjpro 150 win64` from the official website, but when running the GitHub project mentioned above, I found that it was pointing to `mujoco210`. So I put all the subfiles downloaded from `MJPro 150` into a newly created folder named `"mujoco210"`. Could there be any hidden problems with this?

```bash
D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\python.exe D:\wush-group\PythonProject\pytorch-soft-actor-critic-master\main.py 
D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py:555: UserWarning: WARN: The environment HalfCheetah-v2 is out of date. You should consider upgrading to version `v4`.
logger.warn(
cl: ������ warning D9025 :������д��/W3��(�á�/w��)
cl: ������ warning D9002 :����δ֪ѡ�-fopenmp��
dummyshim.c
cl: ������ warning D9025 :������д��/W3��(�á�/w��)
cl: ������ warning D9002 :����δ֪ѡ�-fopenmp��
cymj.c
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 426, in compile
self.spawn(args)
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 524, in spawn
return super().spawn(cmd, env=env)
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1041, in spawn
spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run, **kwargs)
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\spawn.py", line 70, in spawn
D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\mujoco_py\cymj.c(797): fatal error C1083: �޷������ļ�: ��mjui.h��: No such file or directory
raise DistutilsExecError(
distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'D:\\software_install\\Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
During the handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\wush-group\PythonProject\pytorch-soft-actor-critic-master\main.py", line 51, in <module>
env = gym.make(args.env_name)
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 581, in make
env_creator = load(spec_.entry_point)
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 61, in load
mod = importlib.import_module(mod_name)
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\mujoco\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from gym.envs.mujoco.mujoco_env import MujocoEnv, MuJocoPyEnv # isort:skip
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\mujoco\mujoco_env.py", line 11, in <module>
import mujoco_py
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\mujoco_py\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from mujoco_py.builder import cymj, ignore_mujoco_warnings, functions, MujocoException
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\mujoco_py\builder.py", line 504, in <module>
cymj = load_cython_ext(mujoco_path)
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\mujoco_py\builder.py", line 110, in load_cython_ext
cext_so_path = builder.build()
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\mujoco_py\builder.py", line 226, in build
built_so_file_path = self._build_impl()
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\mujoco_py\builder.py", line 249, in _build_impl
dist.run_commands()
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
super().run_command(command)
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
_build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 345, in run
self.build_extensions()
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\mujoco_py\builder.py", line 149, in build_extensions
build_ext.build_extensions(self)
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 195, in build_extensions
_build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 467, in build_extensions
self._build_extensions_serial()
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 493, in _build_extensions_serial
self.build_extension(ext)
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 548, in build_extension
objects = self.compiler.compile(
File "D:\software-install\Anaconda3\envs\torch_UAV\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 428, in compile
raise CompileError(msg)
distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'D:\\software_install\\Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't install a prerequisite library. That library contains (among others) that header file `mjui.h`. For more info on the error itself, search for the error code "C1083", lots of similar questions here. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].